# How to define a custom path in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a User model. If I do:

```
def my_action
  @user = User.new
end
```

then

```
  <% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

I get

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1b4b878>
```

Which make sense because I haven't mapped it going `map.resources :users.`.. but I don't want to do it this way because I don't need all the resources.

How can I just define this `user_path` method in my routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also [customize restful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resources). For example in my application only the index and show actions are appropriate for certain controllers. In my routes.rb file I have some routes like this:

```
map.resources :announcements, :only => [:index, :show]
```

You can also use `:except` if that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

Since I came here looking for a way to create helpers in routes.rb, here is the way to do it:

```
get '/users/:id/' =>'users#show', :as => :user
```

Answer (score 3):

You can map custom routes in your routes.rb file like this...

```
map.users '/users', :controller => 'user', :action => 'index'
```

This gives you the `users_path` helper you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a convention? Like the route to the index is model_path ?

Comment: This is incorrect. This won't solve the form posting cos it's going to the wrong action.  map.resources :users, :only =>[:new, :create] is the appropriate convention.