# How to set routes.rb for ONLY controller and view object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller called store_controller, and views for store. 
But the store doesn't have the model, but I want to use store_path in the code. How can I add the store_path in routes.rb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only one store (without ID) then you can create only a single route (named `store` so you can use `store_path`):

```
map.resource :store, :only => [:show]
```

You can also just create a custom route:

```
map.store "/store", :controller => "store", :action => "show"
```

Comment: I get this error.

undefined local variable or method `store_path' for #<StoreController:0x1032a00b8>

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: I see, restarted, and fixed. Thank you.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you edit any files in the config folder, you normally need to restart the server as even in the development environment it will cache all the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read up a bit more here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resources

Which I poached from this related post:

[How to define a custom path in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436309/how-to-define-a-custom-path-in-rails)